# Linux split a column into two different columns in a same CSV file

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sed, awk

Hi I have a csv file with below entries

```
11
22
13
,,
aa
bb
cc
,,
ww
kk
ll
,,
```

Please suggest me a linux command or script which can split this colomun into 3 columns in the same file like below

```
11  aa  ww
22  bb  kk
13  cc  ll
```

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: I just attempted to fix your formatting please check that what's posted now looks EXACTLY like your real file, including those lines that only have 2 commas in them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it with `awk`.

Create a file named `script.awk`, with the following contents:

```sh
BEGIN {
   line = 0; #Initialize at zero
}
/,,/ { #every time we hit the delimiter
   line = 0; #reset line to zero 
}
!/,,/{ #otherwise
   a[line] = a[line]" "$0; # Add the new input line to the output line
   line++; # increase the counter by one 
}
END {
   for (i in a )
      print a[i] # print the output
}
```

Run file like this:

```
awk -f test.awk < datafile
```

Output:

```
$ cat datafile
11
22
13
,,
aa
bb
cc
,,
ww
kk
ll
,,
$ awk -f script.awk < datafile 
 11 aa ww
 22 bb kk
 13 cc ll
```

Or if you just want a **one-liner**, do this:

```
awk 'BEGIN{line=0;}/,,/{line=0;}!/,,/{a[line++]=a[line]" "$0;}END{for (i in a ) print a[i]}' datafile
```

**EDIT:**

This will add commas between the fields:

```
awk 'BEGIN{line=0;}/,,/{line=0;}!/,,/{a[line++]=a[line]?a[line]","$0:$0;}END{for (i in a ) print a[i]}' datafile
                                                              # ^ This is the part that I changed
```

Comment: dear friend,
working perfectly fine.
the only difference, as it is a csv file your command line is perfectly dividing them into different column but with space. I just had to add extra sed command to replace all occurances of space with commas. 
HATS F TO YOU FRIEND.

Comment: finally 
awk 'BEGIN{line=0;}/,,/{line=0;}!/,,/{a[line++]=a[line]" "$0;}END{for (i in a ) print a[i]}' 1.csv | sed 's/ /,/g' awk.csv > awk2.csv| sed -i 's/,//' awk2.csv

Comment: Ok I can change it for commas. One moment. No need to `sed`

Comment: @user2043380 fixed it so it works without sed.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a nice crazy shell pipeline that actually does what the OP wants :!

```
#% cat t
11
22
13
,,
aa
bb
cc
,,
ww
kk
ll
,,
```

Then

```
#% pr -t -3 -l 4 -s' ' t | sed '$d'
11 aa ww
22 bb kk
13 cc ll
```

I'm sure there's better commands without resorting to code.

**EDIT** Thanks to @user000001 for the heads-up on my error making me revisit my solution.

Comment: Cool! I wasn't aware of the paste command.

Comment: Your output does not match the OP's

Comment: Oooops a subtle point user000001 - perhaps I could get the OP to change his question :( - I'll have to think again.!

Comment: hey buddy,
thanks a ton works fine only the difference is it changes expected columns into rows but certainly we have a fixture for this. thanks a ton buddy.

Answer (score 0):

```
perl -lne 'if(/,,/){$.=0}$a{$.}=$a{$.}." ".$_ if($.!=0);END{foreach (sort keys %a){print $a{$_}}}'
```

Tested below:

```
> cat temp
11
22
13
,,
aa
bb
cc
,,
ww
kk
ll
,,
> perl -lne 'if(/,,/){$.=0}$a{$.}=$a{$.}." ".$_ if($.!=0);END{foreach (sort keys %a){print $a{$_}}}' temp
 11 aa ww
 22 bb kk
 13 cc ll
>
```

Comment: works perfectly fine but same comma saperated issue because it is a csv file. that can be fixed with sed command. thanks a ton.
$ cat t.csv
1,AL,1
1,AZ,5
1,BA,1
,,
1,AR,1
1,AZ,5
1,BA,9
,,
1,AR,1
1,AZ,2
1,BA,1

$ perl -lne 'if(/,,/){$.=0}$a{$.}=$a{$.}." ".$_ if($.!=0);END{foreach (sort keys %a){print $a{$_}}}' t.csv
 1,AL,1 1,AR,1 1,AR,1
 1,AZ,5 1,AZ,5 1,AZ,2
 1,BA,1 1,BA,9 1,BA,1

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you:

```
pr -tT3 -s\  file | sed \$d
```

Answer (score 0):

with awk

```
awk 'BEGIN {RS=",,\n"; FS="[\n]"}{ }{a=a$1" ";b=b$2" ";c=c$3" ";} END{print a"\n"b"\n"c}' temp.txt
```

Output

```
11 aa ww
22 bb kk
13 cc ll
```