# Bash Parse CSV - Formatting Datasets

Tags: bash, shell, unix

I have a csv with the following format:

```
Dataset1,

…

…

Dataset2,

..

..

Dataset3,
```

All the Datasets are separated by blank lines. I would like my bash script to change the formatting of the file to:

```
Dataset1           Dataset2           Dataset3

...                   …                     …

…                     …                     …

…                     …                     …
```

Here's my script:

```
#!/bin/bash
input="/path/to/csv/file/file.cvs"
while IFS=',' read -r f1 f2 f3; do
  if [ -z "$f1 $f2 $f3" ]; then
    awk 'BEGIN{getline to_add < "$f1 $f2 $f3"}{print $0,to_add}' f
  fi
  echo "$f1 $f2 $f3"
done < "$input"
```

Comment: Although with different approach (i.e. awk,perl), I think you can find clues from a post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14709360/linux-split-a-column-into-two-different-columns-in-a-same-csv-file

Answer (score 0):

The below pure shell (no embedded awk/perl) will work. But has limitations. Only works properly with the same number of records in each set. To handle differnt numbers you will need to mainting the count of records in each set and embed emty records `,,,,,,,` as required.

```
set -u

ROW=0
SET=1
MAXROW=0
while read LINE
do
    if [ -z "$LINE" ]
    then
        # New data set
        if [ $ROW -gt $MAXROW ]
        then
            MAXROW=$ROW
        fi
        ROW=0
        SET=$(($SET+1))
    elif [ $SET -eq 1 ]
    then
        DATA[$ROW]="$LINE"
        ROW=$(($ROW+1))
    else
        DATA[$ROW]="${DATA[$ROW]},$LINE"
        ROW=$(($ROW+1))
    fi
done

if [ $ROW -gt $MAXROW ]
then
    MAXROW=$ROW
fi

ROW=0
while [ $ROW -lt $MAXROW ]
do
    echo "${DATA[$ROW]}"
    ROW=$(($ROW+1))
done
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a compact and readable but hacky [bash](/questions/tagged/bash)+[awk](/questions/tagged/awk)+`pr` solution with bad runtime, but it works with arbitrary sets. It uses `awk` to retrieve specific datasets using its paragraph mode and `pr` to display them side by side using process substitution.

```
$ cat csv
Dataset1,
ds1foo1

Dataset2,
ds2foo1,ds2bar1
ds2foo2,ds2bar2

Dataset3,
ds3foo1,ds3bar1,ds3quux1
ds3foo2,ds3bar2,ds3quux2
ds3foo3,ds3bar3,ds3quux3

Dataset4,
ds3foo1,ds3bar1,ds3quux1,ds3quuux1
ds3foo2,ds3bar2,ds3quux2,ds3quuux2
ds3foo3,ds3bar3,ds3quux3,ds3quuux3
ds3foo4,ds3bar4,ds3quux4,ds3quuux4

$ ./columnize_paragraphs.sh csv
Dataset1,                Dataset2,                Dataset3,                Dataset4,
ds1foo1                  ds2foo1,ds2bar1          ds3foo1,ds3bar1,ds3quux1 ds3foo1,ds3bar1,ds3quux1
                         ds2foo2,ds2bar2          ds3foo2,ds3bar2,ds3quux2 ds3foo2,ds3bar2,ds3quux2
                                                  ds3foo3,ds3bar3,ds3quux3 ds3foo3,ds3bar3,ds3quux3
                                                                           ds3foo4,ds3bar4,ds3quux4
```

And the code:

```
#!/bin/bash

get_paragraph_count()
{
    awk 'BEGIN{RS=""}END{print NR}' "$1"
}

get_record()
{
    awk -v record="$2" 'BEGIN{RS=""}NR==record' "$1"
}

columnize_paragraphs()
{
    local file="$1"
    local paragraphs="$(get_paragraph_count "${file}")"
    local args=

    for i in $(seq 1 ${paragraphs}); do
        args="${args} <(get_record '${file}' '${i}')"
    done
    [ -n "${args}" ] && eval "pr -w100 -mt ${args}"
}

for file; do
    [ -e "${file}" ] || continue
    columnize_paragraphs "${file}"
done
```

Depending on how your file looks you will have to play around with the `-w` parameter to `pr` or inject a `fold` during the construction of `args` if you don't care about line-wrapping.